# Three Joins fields in table 2 override those in table 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

users create new customers. customers own subscriptions for products.

```
user
========
user_id
name

customer
========
customer_id
user_id
name

subscription
========
customer_id
product_id
```

I have a products table that stores "master" pricing for all users:

```
product
========
product_id
name
price
```

But i can override SOME or ALL the products' prices  for some users.

```
user_price
========
product_id
user_id
price
```

I'm writing a trigger for a the table subscription that requires the product price/the overridden price. Since the overridden prices are based on user_id but i don't store the user_id on this table, how can i write a statment that retrieves the user_id from the customer table based on customer_id set for this subscription then retrieving the correct price?

```
SELECT `price`
FROM `product` p
LEFT JOIN `user_price` u
    ON u.`user_id` = ???? AND u.`product_id` = NEW.product_id
INTO var_product_price;
```

How efficient is my design? should i keep it like that or start storing user_id on subscription. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this several ways depending on what your database supports.  A case statement would be more flexible, but you can also use the ISNULL function which should be pretty portable.

```
SELECT u.Name [UserName], c.Name [CustomerName], p.Name [Product Name]
, isnull(up.price, p.price) [User or Product Price]
from user u
join customer c on u.user_id = c.user_id
join subscription s on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
left join user_price up on s.product_id = up.product_id and u.user_id =     up.user_id
```

Comment: thanks. How efficient is my deign? should i star storing user_id on subscription also which is redundant but faster?

Comment: It always comes down to the quantity of records and indexing.  You have a fine design and you would only need to put the user_id within the subscription if there ever was a case where one company could have more than one subscription.  The extra join is negligible in most cases.  Now tell me the user table is in a remote database, or it has millions of records and is not indexed by user_id.  You can always find a way to make an otherwise good design work less efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You start with the subscription table, then you join the customers, then you join the user_price.

```
-- you start with subscription and have customer_id and product_id from there
SELECT COALESCE(u.price, p.price) AS final_price

FROM product p
JOIN customer c 
LEFT JOIN user_price u ON u.user_id = c.user_id

WHERE p.product_id = '123' AND c.customer_id = 'ABC'
```

Since you must have a customer for this subscription, you can join them before.

Comment: thanks. How efficient is my deign?  should i star storing user_id on subscription also which is redundant but faster?